# How to replace the 3rd space in a sentence with \n

Tags: php, string, replace, newline

How can I replace the third space, and successive spaces, with `"\n"` in the following sentence?

> Please ask your questions after the session is finished.

Comment: Post your input, expected output and your code...

Comment: Also tells us the problem with your code, as shown by the output of your code.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: every space after, or every 3rd space after?  ambiguous to me

Comment: @juan there seems to be some dispute about your input string's variability and your desired output.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: @juan you have been online in the last 8 hours.  Please do not abandon this page.  Please clarify the question and designate an accepted answer if one of them has solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, should work

```
<?php

$sentence = 'Some really long sentence without any kind of sense';

$se = explode(' ', $sentence);
$s = '';

$i = 0;
while ($i < count($se)) {
    $i++;
    $s .= $se[$i-1];
    if ($i !== count($se)) {
        if ($i%3 == 0) {
            $s .= '\n';
        } else {
            $s .= ' ';
        }
    }
}

echo $s;
```

Comment: Please check your output:
`string(56) "Please ask your\nquestions after the\nsession is finish "`

Comment: "Try this" answers are low value on StackOverflow.  Always include an explanation with every answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str    = 'Please ask your questions after the session is finish';
$words  = explode(' ', $str);
$result = '';
foreach($words as $k => $word)
    $result .= $word . ($k<2 ? ' ' : "\n");
var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
string(54) "Please ask your
questions
after
the
session
is
finish
"
```

Comment: There is a trailing new line here.  You could trim the result to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is an excellent choice here because it doesn't require any "chopping" at the input string to run iterated operations and once you wrap your head around the [\G (continue anchor)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) "magic", it is a rather straightforward expression.  If this was my project, I would use regex over a non-regex approach because it is a direct and concise one-liner while any performance losses will be completely unnoticeable to the end user given the sample input string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/mhjNR))

```
$string = "Please ask your questions after the session is finished.";
echo preg_replace('~(?:^\S+ \S+ |\G(?!^))\S+\K ~', "\n", $string);
```

Output:

```
Please ask your
questions
after
the
session
is
finished.
```

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kkeLoH/2)

```
~          #pattern delimiter
(?:        #start of non-capturing group
  ^        #match start of string
  \S+ \S+  #match one or more visible characters, a literal space, one or more visible characters, a literal space
  |        #or
  \G(?!^)  #continue from last match, but not the start of the string
)          #end of non-capturing group
\S+        #match one or more visible characters
\K         #restart the fullstring match (ignore previously matched characters)
           #match a literal space  (the only replaced character)
~          #pattern delimiter
```

*In the event that there are no qualifying spaces to replace in the input string, the input string will remain unchanged as desired and no errors/warnings/notices will be generated.

Answer (score 0):

One way to replace the 3rd whitespace and successive spaces with a newline `\n` is to get the offset in the string of the third occurrance and use that to replace the character.

To get the offset you might use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), use `\h+` to match one or more times a horizontal whitespace character and use the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag. *(from the docs)* If this flag is passed, for every occurring match the appendant string offset will also be returned.

To replace the character you might use [substr_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php).

For the `start` parameter use  `$matches[0][2][1]` and for the length parameter use `$matches[0][2][0]`. Index 0 is the returned array, index 2 is the third match, index 0 contains the match and index 1 contains the offset.

```
$str = "Please ask your questions after the session is finished.";
preg_match_all('/\h+/', $str,$matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$str = substr_replace($str, "\n", $matches[0][2][1], strlen($matches[0][2][0]));
echo $str;
```

Will result in:

```
Please ask your
questions after the session is finished.
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/3qg9C)

Comment: Have you added complexity to this question? Would you actually use this solution if this was your project?

Comment: @mickmackusa I read this question as replace the third space and successive spaces with `\n`.

Comment: I'll admit that there is some ambiguity in the terminology, but you have modified the sample input string -- the only piece of context provided.

Comment: You are right, I changed it to point out the successive spaces. I have put the original example back in my answer.